# Visual Studio code keeps offering me to close tags after it was already closed

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio code keeps offering me to close  tag after it was already closed.

Do you have any idea?

[image]

Comment: I think that you should report that to the VSTeam using the lower right corner smiley / frown face :) I also experienced that issue, a bit annoying.. so I will keep an eye in the post to see if there is a fix

Comment: https://twitter.com/hagailuger/status/912657855496548352